# Access denied to URL when deployed in Windows Azure?

Tags: wcf, azure, castle-windsor

I have a WCF service hosted in an Azure WorkerRole. Everything works as expected on localhost but when deployed in Azure there's the following permission problem (found in the Event Viewer)

> Exception: HTTP could not register URL `https://+:5253/IServiceName/`.
>   Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see
>   `http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353` for details).

(I'm using Castle Windsor WCF to create dependency injected services, but behind the scenes it's basically a ServiceHost with the base address set to `https://<instance-ip-endpoint>.cloudapp.net:<endpoint-port>/IServiceName` and a `WSHttpBinding` on top.)

I copy-pasted the code from another of my projects, which works just fine on Azure.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this? Isn't the deployment supposed to have access to it's own endpoint?

Comment: Do you have port 5253 set up as an endpoint in your csdef file?

Comment: Yes I do. "Input" with both public and private port on 5253.

Comment: You should share your `csdef`. Do you have a **certificate** assigned and using an **https** protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this error because of (what seems like) an exception due to a missing assembly reference in the cloud.

When marking missing assemblies (some app-specific) with CopyLocal and redeploying the errors go away.

(Sidenote: The error about access rights isn't really helpful for troubleshooting though)